# aspnet table - specify TableCell width?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've a asp.net table and I'm trying to format my columns to be all equal widths, or say 4 columns of 20%, 30%, 20% and 30%.  However the following code is not working:

```
<asp:TableCell Width="30%">
```

The 'height' attribute works but this isn't the one I'm after.  Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

It's not working because the [Width property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.width.aspx) is expecting a value of a [Unit type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit.aspx), which defaults to Pixels..  I couldn't find an example that shows how to create an instance of Unit with a Type of Percentage

Which leaves me to suggest how you could do it with CSS..

1. Give the TableCell a CssClass, and set the Width in a stylesheet

   `<asp:TableCell CssClass="tableCellWidth30">`

   `.tableCellWidth30 { width:30%; }`
2. Use the Style property and set the Width inline

   `<asp:TableCell Style="width:30%;">`

Comment: Many thanks - I've give the cell a css class which seems to have fixed it!

Comment: To use a percentage use the static method Unit.Percentage(30)

Comment: hmm... can't seem to get it to work using markup, only code-behind. However, I just tried using a percentage like your example and it worked just fine. Does the percentage not come through for you at all?

Comment: @Chris - no, I was just curious if `Unit.Percentage(30)` was possible in markup.. I'd tried it following your suggestion but I couldn't get it to work so I just thought I'd ask how you'd done it!  :o)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add a css style via code, do it like this:

```
txtmark.Style("font-weight") = "normal"
```

I couldn't find this answer anywhere, so that is why i posted it here.