# Why 100% doesn't work with panels inside tablecells?

Tags: asp.net, panel, tablecell

I put a panel inside a tablecell and set the width and height properties to **100%** in order for the panel to take the 100% space of the tablecell, but the panel disappears when I do that.
Only when I set the panel width and height properties to **100px**, only then it is shown.
So how can I set the panel to always take 100% of the tablecell it is in?

In this example the panels don't show:

```
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="mainTable" Width="100%" Height="100%" BorderColor="Red" BorderWidth="20px" BorderStyle="Solid">
    <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="mainRow" Width="100%" Height="100%" BorderColor="Purple" BorderWidth="20px" BorderStyle="Solid">
        <asp:TableCell runat="server" ID="maincell" Width="30%" Height="100%" BorderColor="AliceBlue" BorderWidth="20px" BorderStyle="Solid">
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="mainpanel" Width="100%" Height="100%" BackColor="Gainsboro"></asp:Panel>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server" ID="TableCell1" Width="30%" Height="100%" BorderColor="AliceBlue" BorderWidth="20px" BorderStyle="Solid">
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1" Width="100%" Height="100%" BackColor="Gainsboro"></asp:Panel>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server" ID="TableCell2" Width="30%" Height="100%" BorderColor="AliceBlue" BorderWidth="20px" BorderStyle="Solid">
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel2" Width="100%" Height="100%" BackColor="Gainsboro"></asp:Panel>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:table>
```

I put a panel inside the cell because I want to put controls inside it later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a Unit type as it defaults to pixels (apparently). I cant find out how to specify it in markup so cant really help.

This question has the similar issue: [aspnet table - specify TableCell width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490486/aspnet-table-specify-tablecell-width)

They suggest using CSS instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.width.aspx#Y0

webControl.width = Unit.Percentage(100) should work, again not sure where you'd put this as I don't do ASP.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to flaw/optimazation in the browser. The web page renders into correct html, but when the browser renders the page it will skip/remove empty divs. So if you insert some kind of content into one of the divs like &nbsp; the browser will render the divs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

putting `style="empty-cells: show"` on TableCell, IE7 and FF renders it correctly, but in IE9 it does take the space but not the background-color

```
        <asp:TableCell runat="server" ID="maincell" Width="30%" Height="100%" BorderColor="AliceBlue"
            BorderWidth="20px" BorderStyle="Solid" style="empty-cells: show">
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="mainpanel" Width="100%" Height="100%" BackColor="Gainsboro">
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:TableCell>
```

play around in css and set the correct style for each browser. that's how tiring it is. :/